# Initialisation of SFMCSDK is not compatible with Objective-C

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-ios, salesforcesdk

I am trying to initialise in Objective-C.

In Swift the method is:

`[SFMCSdk initializeSdk: ConfigBuilder().setPush(config: mobilePushConfiguration, onCompletion: completionHandler).build()];`

But it could not initialise with Objective-C.

Before updated the library, the method is:

`[[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_configureWithDictionary:[builder sfmc_build] error:&error];`

Can anyone help to write this method in Objective-C?!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create pushConfigBuilder and build the PushConfig.
Then initialize the  sdk as shown below:

```
  PushConfigBuilder *pushConfigBuilder = [[PushConfigBuilder alloc] initWithAppId:@""];
    pushConfigBuilder = [pushConfigBuilder setAccessToken:@""];
    pushConfigBuilder =  [pushConfigBuilder setMarketingCloudServerUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
    pushConfigBuilder = [pushConfigBuilder setMid:@""];
    pushConfigBuilder = [pushConfigBuilder setAnalyticsEnabled:YES];
    pushConfigBuilder = [pushConfigBuilder setInboxEnabled:YES];
    pushConfigBuilder = [pushConfigBuilder setLocationEnabled:YES];
    pushConfigBuilder = [pushConfigBuilder setEnableScreenEntryTracking:NO];
    PushConfig *pushConfig = [pushConfigBuilder build];
    
    void (^completionHandler)(OperationResult) = ^(OperationResult result) {
        switch(result) {
            case OperationResultError:
                break;
            case OperationResultSuccess:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
    
    
    SFMCSdkConfigBuilder *configBuilder = [[SFMCSdkConfigBuilder alloc] init];
    configBuilder = [configBuilder setPushWithConfig:pushConfig onCompletion:completionHandler];
    
    
    [SFMCSdk initializeSdk:[configBuilder build]];
```

Thanks,
Prakashini

Comment: Thanks for this answer.But When I use this it is jump in "OperationResultTimeout".
How can this will be successfully initialised.